# Who replaces a heavily rusted gas governor in new home meter box?

Tags: gas, uk, meter, rust

I recently purchased a house and had someone in to quote for a new boiler. He noted that the gas governor was very rusted and should be replaced, and he said that I should ring the gas emergency number to explain.

I have called the gas emergency and they won’t help as we don’t smell gas/suspect a leak. They referred me to my supplier (Scottish power) who also didn’t want to fix it, but the guy on the phone didn’t really know what I was talking about..

Who should I contact to replace this part?

Thanks
Josh

Comment: In most places the gas meter is owned by the gas supplier and is up to them to maintain.  Most other parts of gas system in your house is yours to pay to maintain/have inspected, by the gas company or their list of licensed gas workers.

Comment: Could use google to find the parts of a gas meter(hopefully with the local names).  You will then know the proper words used when describing your problem.  Picture should show if it is cosmetic surface rust or a more serious problem(rust eating into the device).

Comment: A picture of the layout showing the location of the governor and its relation to the gas meter would be helpful here. You can add it to your question by using the "Edit" button below the question text, followed by selecting the "Moon and Mountains" button that appears above the resulting text composition box.

Answer (score 4):

#### Who should I contact to replace the gas governor?

Is it upstream or downstream of the gas meter? It is normally upstream (between the shutoff valve and the gas meter).

> Preferably, place the regulator on the intake manifold and the gas shut off valve on the gas supply pipe.
>
> [image]

Source: [Can a Gas Regulator Be Installed Vertically? - Norgas Controls](https://norgascontrols.com/blog/can-a-gas-regulator-be-installed-vertically/)

> A gas service regulator is connected to the end of the service pipe **before the gas meter** to reduce the gas pressure to supply gas appliances installed in the premises.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Source: [Medium Pressure Gas | Gas Meters & Installation | Plus Hazards & Costs](https://www.gasconnections.co.uk/medium-pressure-gas-meters-installation/)

In the UK the supplier (in this case Scottish power) is only responsible for the gas meter itself.

The rest of the connection is either the responsibility of the distributor (if upstream of the meter) or the property owner (if downstream of the meter and including the meter cabinet).

The supplier (who you pay for gas/electricity) is a different entity to the distributor (in the vast majority of cases)

The distributor is location dependent in the UK. So if it is upstream contact one of the following.

**Regional gas distribution networks**

> The regional gas distribution networks are medium to low-pressure pipe
> networks connecting the national gas transmission networks to
> individual properties in the region. There are five regional gas
> distribution networks:
>
> - Scotland, operated by SGN
> - North of England, operated by Northern Gas Networks
> - London, West Midlands and East of England, operated by Cadent
> - South of England, operated by SGN
> - Wales and South West England, operated by Wales & West Utilities

Source: [British gas distribution networks | AquaSwitch](https://www.aquaswitch.co.uk/blog/british-gas-distribution-networks/)

There is also a number of small independent gas transporters

<sup>Disclaimer: I work on behalf of a large UK power company.</sup>

Further Reading:

- https://www.energybrokers.co.uk/gas/gas-network (includes a map of the main distributor areas)